# Android Error Webview Not Working

Tags: android, button, browser, webview, native

I am attempting to create an android app that when a webview is created it can be interacted with without having the device open the native web browser. I have looked at other questions here and I have created this code following some other advice I have seen online. However my code is not working. What appears to be wrong?

Here is my activity code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;



public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });



         WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
         myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){        
           @Override
           public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent(WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
            view.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
            return false;
           }
         });
   }
}
```

And here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Back" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my edit, still has a syntax error. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong in regards to syntax.

```
 WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading("WebView: view, String, https://www.google.com/") {
        view.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
        return false;
        }
    });};}
```

Comment: You need to include the logcat so we can see the errors

Comment: Eclipse will not allow me to run the application.

Comment: Well your strings in the `Webview` are not contained in quotes  `" "`

Comment: Let me know if that fixes it so I can post an answer and you can accept it

Comment: Hey, you have a syntax error in your code, first you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Posted edit to my code

Comment: Man... you must be new to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've already commented, you have syntax error in your code. I've fixed it however you're missing another point. You don't need to specify the url while overriding `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` method.

Following code snippet gives you a hint that how method can be overridden.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){     
   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      view.loadUrl(url);
      return false;
   }
});
```

After you setup the `WebViewClient` you should call `loadUrl(..)` method like following.

```
myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

Btw, if your `WebViewClient` tries to load hardcoded url, it does not work fine. Let's say if you desire to load `"https://www.facebook.com"`, it will load again `"https://www.google.com"`. Therefore, `WebView` must load the url given as parameter everytime.

And one more thing, you should specify permission on your `AndroidManifest.xml` so that application loads content from Internet.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Do not forget to add the permission stated above.

Hope this may help.

Comment: My eclipse is still telling me that code is filled with syntax errors. What could be going wrong? Even just the first part you gave gives 3 syntax errors.

     WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
     myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){     
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
           view.loadUrl(url);
           return false;
        }
     });}

Answer (score -1):

You want something like this.

```
shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView: view, String webPage)
```

Then add **this**:

```
WebPage = "https://www.google.com/";
```

And change **this**:

```
view.loadUrl(webPage);
return false;
```

So the final code would look something like **this**:

```
shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView: view, String webPage){
    WebPage = "https://www.google.com/";
    view.loadUrl(webPage);
    return false;
}
```